# Consuming a REST api in Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, api, callout, after-trigger, third-party

I need to create an integration between Salesforce and a third party service. Essentially Salesforce will trigger a callout to the third party when a status change occurs on a custom object record. The unique identifier in both systems will be the email address. When the status changes I need to retrieve assessment information and push it back into Salesforce on the same record. How do I do this??

I know that I need to create a trigger that calls a class to request information from the third party system. What would the initial trigger look like? It needs to run when the status changes from '8 - Offer Accepted' to '9 - Induction Booked', and call an HTTP request class. Is there anything I'm missing?

Many Thanks,
Natasha

Comment: One starting point: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts.

Comment: Thanks Keith I'm already doing the trailhead. I need help with creating the initial trigger to call the HTTP class

Answer (score 2):

On your trigger call a method which is in a class. This method should be a static method with the `@future(callout=true)` annotation

Here is a trailhead module 
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

Here is a very similar question that might help you as well with tradeoffs ... this is a not a great approach btw, because you could blow out your API limits
[How to update a record in a trigger with value from a REST API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238807/how-to-update-a-record-in-a-trigger-with-value-from-a-rest-api#238808)

Comment: How do I use the email address as the unique identifier in both systems so the correct record is chosen?